# How to prove inequality in positives?

Tags: inequality

How to prove that inequality?

$$
\frac{1}{a^4b+b^3} + \frac{1}{ab^4+a^3} \leq \frac{1}{a^2b^2}, a, b \in (0, \infty) 
$$

Comment: What is the inequality here?  I see an equality.

Comment: Make use of the excellent hint provided by @BRIC-Fan below. If you are not familiar with the AM-GM inequality then see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**: $a^4b+b^3 \geq 2a^2b^2, ab^4+a^3 \geq 2a^2b^2$ by AM-GM inequality.